# Converting CSV to shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have a CSV file with lat and long coordinates, is there a way I can convert it into a shapefile so as to generate a mobile network coverage map like the AT&T image I have attached.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have a 3D Analyst license, you can do this:

Add the CSV file to ArcMap, right-click on it and select *Display XY data*. Select appropriate values in the shown dialog, press OK. A new featureclass will be added to the map. Right-click on that, select *Data*, *Export Data*.

Alternatively, in ArcCatalog, right-click on the CSV file, select *Create Featureclass*, *From XY table*.

Comment: ok I am almost done downloading finishing up my ArcGis for desktop apparently its has the ArcMap tool you are referring to ?

Comment: @Zidane, yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

What about to use [ASCII 3D to feature class tool](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/3d_analyst_tools/ascii_3d_to_feature_class_3d_analyst_.htm)? If your point doesn't have Z value, you could use for Z value for expample value 1. I assume you have only X and Y values.

Comment: @Zidane: That tool is part of ArcGIS Desktop, but you need a 3D Analyst license to use it.

Comment: @Berend I have opted to use the trial version for now

Comment: @Zidane: So you have acces to 3D Analys license?

Comment: @Berend   I have now created my project in QGIS is there anyway I can port it to tilemill so that I can save it as mbTiles for use with mapbox

Comment: @Zidane, Sorry I cannot help you with that. BTW it doesn't seem to be related to the original question, so please post it as a separate question.

Comment: Sure let me do that

Answer (score 0):

I tried to automate the process using addin.

[Download CSV2SHP.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MbJVhHQyM3MOho2GE_LfIZZYldaCAZDX/view?usp=sharing)

In the combobox type the full path of the csv file including the csv file name e.g. `C:\page\docs\test.csv`

Then press enter and click on the convert button.

It will convert the csv file to a point shapefile and save it in the same directory within a folder name of the csv file i.e. `C:\page\docs\test\`

The output shapefile will be having a reference of WGS-1984.