# CSV to shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv

I  converted a shapefile into a CSV in order to do some calculations with the data and add some columns to the attribute table. I cannot seem to find out how to convert it to a geolocalized file again? I have lat and long coordinates but I am working with polygons delimited as  c- squares.

Comment: How did you convert to CSV? Do you know how to load a CSV into QGIS? Why didn't you do the calculations in QGIS?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179827/converting-csv-to-shapefile please see this query

Comment: @MKR: the linked question is about ArcGIS, the OP here asks for QGIS. However, Erik is right, calculations should be done in QGIS.

Comment: Shapefiles are a bundle of several files. One of them is the attribute table. Have you converted only this file to CSV?

Comment: Don't try to retroject your CSV, but join your new attributes (calculations) with the ID to your original shapefile.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answers, I did the calculations in R and excel because I had to add new fields and I did not know how to do it in qgis since my new fields are dependent on pre-existing ones. I exported the whole shapefile to csv (as far as I know) i do have lat and long and other geographic information but do not know how to use it  to specify polygon geometry. when i join my shapefile by location with the non-geolocalized   file my creates attributes appear as "NULL"

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122875/geopandas-how-to-read-a-csv-and-convert-to-a-geopandas-dataframe-with-polygons) for .csv to .shp. Look into the [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) for performing calculations on pre-existing data. And/or post another question if you still need help.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I see you using R so I suggest to use the `{sf}` package. You don't even need to convert to between csv and shapefile, `{sf}` + `{dplyr}` allow you to read shapefiles, do some calculations and save results as another shapefile.

An example would be:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

my_sf_data <- st_read(<your shapefile>)

results <- my_sf_data %>%
    filter(...) %>% # or any dplyr action
    mutate(...)

st_write(results, <new shapefile>)
```